# How to match the variable in switch with contents of a list?

Tags: list, tcl, switch-statement

I have a doubt concerning the use of switch in tcl. Mainly, I was wondering if it was possible to make something like:

```
switch myvar {
    list1 {
        puts "myvar matches contents of list1"; }
    list2 {
        puts "myvar matches contents of list2"; }
    default {
        puts "myvar doesn't match any content of any list"; }
}
```

In here, list1 and list2 would be either a list or array of strings containing the names of different files.

Is this even possible without making a very detailed regexp search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite it as an if elseif else construct easily, as Brian Fenton already said (and simplify it with the 'in' operator too.

```
if {$myvar in $list1} {
    puts "myvar matches content of list"
} elseif {$myvar in $list2} {
    puts "myvar matches content of list2"
} elseif {
    puts "myvar doesn't match any content of any list"
}
```

You could of course wrap up the code and write your own switch version that does what you want, after all, this is Tcl...

```
proc listswitch {item conditions} {
     if {[llength $conditions] % 2} {
         return -code error "Conditions must be pairs"
     }
     set code ""
     foreach {cond block} $conditions {
        if {$cond eq "default"} { 
          set code $block
          break 
        } elseif {$item in $cond} {
          set code $block
          break
        }
     }
     if {$code ne ""} {
         uplevel 1 $code
     }
}


listswitch 10 {
   {10 20 30 50} {
       puts "Match in list 1" }
   {50 20 90 11} { 
       puts "Match in list 2"
    }
    default {
       puts "No match"
    }
}
```

You need to worry a little if you want to match filenames literally, or what kind of equality your interested in though. There are some subtle things there, like case insensitive filesystems, different directory separators, absolute vs. relative and even stuff like filesystem encodings which might change the outcome.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not planning on worrying too much about problems in the comparison; it is in the end a very simple check what I need. But I think that the nested ifs-elses should cover the issue.

The one advantage I see from making a personal version of this list-comparing switch is that with some work it could be made to accept variable amounts of input lists (not just mylist1 and mylist2), probably with some loops. The ifs-elses need to be modified if there are any changes in input amounts.

Comment: I'd put the `uplevel` outside the loop so that any `break` or `continue` in the caller's script isn't consumed. But it's a nice solution.

Comment: @Donal Fellows: True, also there should be a break in the default case too, in case someone uses 'default' twice.

Comment: Not really; Tcl's `switch` only recognizes `default` as special when it is the last arm.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question Jason. At first, I thought you wanted a way to compare the contents of two lists. But I think you want to check if the string is a member of the lists. I don't see any easy way to do that with **switch**, so what I would do is very simply to use **lsearch**.

```
if {[lsearch $list1 $myvar ] != -1} {
  puts "myvar matches contents of list1"; }
} elseif {[lsearch $list2 $myvar ] != -1} {
  puts "myvar matches contents of list2"; }
} else
  puts "myvar doesn't match any content of any list"; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick too, true. I was just hoping that there was a possibility of accessing various contents of the variables the switch compares to. Thanks!